# CSS nth-of-type issues

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target my 2/3, 6/7, 10 etc elements using `nth-of-type` only I can't seem to get it working right. Is it possible to target these elements using nth-of-type or would I achieve it best using JS?

```
ul {overflow:hidden; width:300px;}
ul li {width:150px; float:left;  background:#ff0000;}
ul li:nth-of-type(3n+1){  
  background:#fff;
}
```

https://codepen.io/liamgallagher/pen/wjGGGP

Comment: can you explain a bit more what kind of pattern are you trying to get? I don't get the 2/3, 6/7. 10 format

Comment: what is 2/3, 6/7?

Comment: your css is targeting 1st,4th, 7th and 10th...
Do you want 2,3,6,7,10 to be targeted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 2 loop

```css
    ul {overflow:hidden; width:300px;}
    ul li {width:150px; float:left;  background:#ff0000;}
    ul li:nth-of-type(4n+1){
      background:#fff;
    }
    ul li:nth-of-type(4n){
      background:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>WHITE</li>
  <li>RED</li>
  <li>RED</li>
  <li>WHITE</li>
  <li>WHITE</li>
  <li>RED</li>
  <li>RED</li>
  <li>WHITE</li>
  <li>WHITE</li>
  <li>RED</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Liam you can simplify with only one rule (4n+2)

Comment: @VXp i was fast, i forget the 4n+3 also

Comment: @VXp they will if we inverse the colors ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use 2 rules for selectors to achieve what you are looking for. Try this code.

```
ul {overflow:hidden; width:300px;}
ul li {width:150px; float:left;  background:#fff;}
ul li:nth-of-type(4n+2),
ul li:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want the 2, 6, 10… You need `4n` (select each 4th element).
Then, for `n`=0, you need to add `+2`. => `4n+2`
And, as you also want the 3, 7, 11… You need the same, with `+3`.

These are two different selectors, which you can use like in this working snippet:
(I added CSS counters to easily see the number of the `li`s)

```css
ul {overflow:hidden; width:300px;}
ul li {width:150px; float:left;  background:#ff0000;}

ul {
  counter-reset: list;
}

ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:before {
  counter-increment: list;
  content: counter(list);
  position: absolute;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(4n+2),
ul li:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
  <li>__</li>
</ul>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 2 seperate css selectors for the `li` elements

```
ul li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  background: #fff;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
  background: #fff;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjGGWm